# gridlayout with button click not clicking

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridlayout

gridlyout button not clicking here is the code for xml and and java

**layout**

```
<GridLayout 
            android:id="@+id/numerickeypad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:columnCount="10"
            android:rowCount="9" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadone"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:onClick="numerickeypadone" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadtwo"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/two" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadthree"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/three" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadfour"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/four" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadfive"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/five" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadsix"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/six" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadseven"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/seven" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadeight"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/eight" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadnine"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/nine" /> 
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadzero"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/zero" />      
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/dialogbox_numerickeypadclear"
                android:layout_columnSpan="6"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="@string/dialogc" />                               


            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="7"
                android:layout_row="8" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_row="8" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="0" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="1" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="2" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="3" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="4" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="5" />

            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="6" />
            <Space
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:layout_row="7" />



            </GridLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
public void numerickeypadone(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DialogBox.this, "number 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: You have added on click method only for button with text "1" so only that button will show toast message.Can you tell wt exactly you are looking for.

Comment: when i click on button nothing happens thats my problem i have no idea why its not working it should toast a message 1 right?

Comment: add  android:onClick="numerickeypadone" to all buttons in xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have define `android:onClick="numerickeypadone"` action in only first button. 
give the `onclick` action in all buttons.